# UI Testing and NSTextView

Tags: nstextview, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writing an text editor that use autocoloring syntax. I would like to test my *NSTextView* behavior in the UI tests but I'm wondering how can I check that the content is well updated.

For now I'm only able to check the text content:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
while app.windows.count > 0 {
    app.typeKey("w", modifierFlags:.Command)
}

app.typeKey("n", modifierFlags:.Command)
let window = app.windows["Untitled"]

let textView = window.scrollViews.childrenMatchingType(.TextView)
textView.element.typeText("@Martin")

if let content = textView.element.value as? String {
    XCTAssertEqual(content, "@Martin")
} else {
    XCTFail()
}
```

How can I check that my "@" is blue for example?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last assertion. The UI Testing framework will automatically fail if the text passed to `typeText()` doesn't update the text field correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Reading you answer I realized my question wasn't well asked. I just edited it.